# Encoding of a zip file

Tags: character-encoding, locale, zip, mp3, id3

When I extract some file (mp3) with japanese or korean characters within its filename on Windows, they appear normally, but when I extract it on Linux (Ubuntu/Mint) they appear as something like this

```
5thƒAƒ‹ƒoƒ€w1“x 
“¡“c–ƒˆßŽq
03 ‘²‹Æ
?????
```

The question is:

1. How to fix those already extracted files?
2. How to fix the id3 tags also when I don't know what's the correct text/characters?
3. How to make extraction defaults as Windows' character encoding?

Comment: use `p7zip`: it will safely convert encodings. To fix tags you can use `mid3iconv`.

Comment: Re (3): The filenames in Linux are just strings of bytes, the encoding your account shows them in is presumably UTF-8 (haven't seen anything else for some time). Also, the [Zip format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) does handle UTF-8, presumably the original filenames where something else...

Answer (score 2):

1- you can use `convmv -f xxx -t yyy --notest .` in your folder contains those already extracted files/folders. xxx means your Windows encoding, gbk and so on; yyy is your Linux encoding, utf8 and so on.

3- you can use file-roller(Ark is not supported), uninstall unzip package and install p7zip-full packages.

Comment: No need to uninstall unzip or install file-roller if you install p7zip, just use 7z directly

Answer (score 2):

This is because vanilla p7zip can not select proper code page for archives created by Windows. I made a patch for p7zip fixing this issue. You may install patched p7zip with proper code page selection code from here:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:alkisg/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install p7zip p7zip-full
```

Discussion: https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/issues/5

Answer (score 1):

This issue with zips has been [fixed](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/commit/73a19074dbe81fd25913dc5282825cb2ca9f8ceb) in the most recent [far2l file and archive manager](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l). For zip legacy charset detection by far2l to work properly, your system language setting should match the one set on the system where the archive was created (Windows' internal "zip folders" tool uses just the same logic). Also you can do

```
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 far2l
```

for Japanese or

```
LANG=ko_KR.UTF-8 far2l
```

for Korean