# Encoding of cyrillic filenames in zip files

Tags: character-encoding, zip

There are a few questions here about non-ASCII letters in the names of files stored as streams inside zip files ([Hebrew](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251969/17649), [Chinese](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/266442/17649), [Japanese or Korean](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70980/17649)). However none of the solutions provided helped me with a zipfile with Cyrillic letters that came from a Windows machine.

The file has a cyrillic name itself ([Космос.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qk7uf8w2oxzazp7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81.zip?dl=1) - downloadable link). This is an archive with zero-length contents just for the purpose of illustration.

`unzip -l` prints:

```
Archive:  Космос.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-05-03 18:19   ɫ���߼��/ict_inf.pdf
---------                     -------
        0                     1 file
```

The ugly `ɫ���߼��` stands for the sequence of bytes `C9 AB DF E8 AB DF BC AB DF`.

I know (by using GMail preview feature) that this should be

```
Archive:  Космос.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-05-03 18:19   РосКосмос/ict_inf.pdf
---------                     -------
        0                     1 file
```

That is we need to map `C9 AB DF E8 AB DF BC AB DF` to `РосКосмос`.

There are several commonly used 8-bit cyrillic encodings: CP1251, CP866, ISO8859-5, however they would have this word encoded as a different sequence of bytes:

```
           Р  о  с  К  о  с  м  о  с
CP866:     90 AE E1 8A AE E1 AC AE E1
CP1251:    D0 EE F1 CA EE F1 EC EE F1
ISO8859-5: C0 DE E1 BA DE E1 DC DE E1
```

Clearly none of the commonly used 8-bit cyrillic encodings would decode the input names to the output names like this. There is something more complicated at work here.

If only we knew how to decode the names, renaming the files after extraction would be easy with an appropriate `find` script (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252000/17649), e.g.

```
find -mindepth 1 -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | here-goes-the-decoding pipeline )"' sh {} \;
```

or the [convmv](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/) utility.

Comment: By the way: Inside the file, the name is stored as CP866: 90 AE E1 ...; obviously the unzip tool did some conversion - and the conversion was wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ZIP file used with a "recent" infozip displays the right filenames:

```
unzip -l Russian-Космос.zip 
Archive:  Russian-Космос.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-05-03 18:19   РосКосмос/ict_inf.pdf
---------                     -------
        0                     1 file
```

And unzip correctly creates the `РосКосмос/` directory when unzipping.

UTF-8 support has been added to infozip long ago. Executables on my Ubuntu:

```
UnZip 6.00, 20 April 2009
Zip 3.0,  July 5th 2008
```

So your problem may be an ancient InfoZip version (or a version compiled without UTF-8  support)

In my version, `strings /usr/bin/unzip | grep -A8 -B8 'UTF-8'` yields, among other things:

```
ZIP64_SUPPORT (archives using Zip64 for large files supported)
LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT (large files over 2 GiB supported)
other
UTF-8
UNICODE_SUPPORT [wide-chars, char coding: %s] (handle UTF-8 paths)
USE_DEFLATE64 (PKZIP 4.x Deflate64(tm) supported)
USE_UNSHRINK (PKZIP/Zip 1.x unshrinking method supported)
```

which seems to be related to compile/build options

Comment: Interesting, it does *not* work for me. I am using the same Info-ZIP UnZip 6.00 but from OpenSUSE distribution. Will investigate.

Comment: UTF-8 support is a compile-time option, possibly not used in your distro. See my edited answer.

Comment: I did not test it but my impression is that the issue is caused by the `unzip-iso8859_2.patch` that is applied to OpenSUSE packaged unzip [since Jan 24, 2002](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Leap:15.1/unzip/unzip.changes?expand=1). Will probably file a bug report.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to recompile your own...

Answer (score 9):

I have found a solution on the OpenNET.ru forum, a popular Russian-language resource that is dedicated to open-source software and technologies since 1996. A [post on OpenNET](http://www.opennet.ru/tips/info/2494.shtml) suggests that Info-ZIP, once a popular set of tools for handling ZIP archives on computers running MS-DOS assumed that on MS-DOS there is only one 8-bit encoding, namely CP850, therefore all filenames are automatically run through `CP850->CP1252` conversion. CP1252 was probably chosen as the most popular approximation of the ISO-8859-1 character set encoding.

Therefore the correct find command to run after extracting an archive containing Cyrillic filenames would be

```
find -mindepth 1 -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | iconv -f cp1252 -t cp850 | iconv -f cp866 )"' sh {} \;
```

Interestingly one can find suggestions to use not CP1252 but ISO-8859-1. This does not seem to be the case as one some of the archives that I have encountered the transformation `iconv -f iso8859-1 -t cp850` failed while `iconv -f cp1252 -t cp850` converted successfully.

Getting back to individual characters

```
           Р  о  с  К  о  с  м  о  с
CP866:     90 AE E1 8A AE E1 AC AE E1
```

Now applying CP850 -> CP1252 results in `C9 AB DF E8 AB DF BC AB DF`. Exactly the sequence that we have observed.

Another useful command would be

```
 unzip -l РосКосмос.zip | grep -aEv '^Archive:' | iconv -f iso8859-1 -t cp850 | iconv -f cp866
```

To get a list of files from the archive

```
 Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-05-03 18:19   РосКосмос/ict_inf.pdf
---------                     -------
        0                     1 file
```

Filtering away the line that starts with `Archive:` is a protection to hide the name of the archive from conversion.

Answer (score 2):

This issue with zips has been [fixed](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/commit/73a19074dbe81fd25913dc5282825cb2ca9f8ceb) in the most recent [far2l file and archive manager](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l). For zip legacy charset detection by far2l to work properly, your system language setting should match the one set on the system where the archive was created (Windows' internal "zip folders" tool uses just the same logic). Also you can do

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 far2l
```

Comment: Are you personally associated with that project?

Comment: I did some research for it, and wrote few patches, but most of the work was done by it's author, elfmz

Answer (score 1):

OEM code page selection is broken in both vanilla unzip and vanilla p7zip.
I made a [patch](https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/issues/5#issuecomment-659165691) fixing this issue and there is [ppa for Ubuntu](https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/issues/5#issuecomment-649217455) with p7zip with this patch applied.